# How to generate jsDoc for our reactjs actions?

Tags: reactjs, action, jsdoc

My action page is like this:-

```
/**
 * use to clear all the state of model page
 * @function :clearModelState
 */
export function clearModelState() {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_DEVICE_CLEAR,
    deviceList: [],
    deviceTotalCount: 0,
    deviceStatus: [],
    loadingDeviceStatus: false,
    loadingDevice: false,
    isAddLayoutPopupOpen: false,
    isEditDeviceModel: false,
    addDeviceOpen: false,
    customAlertPopUp: false,
    loadMoreDevice: false,
  };
}
```

> The above action we added in one of our action page. When I am running
>   the command jsdoc src -r -d docs all other component, container's doc
>   in generated in docs folder but this action file is not added. How can
>   I write the comment here also to include this in jsDoc?